# Excluding a value when calling pandas describe function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, nan

To deal with NaN values in two columns, I replaced them with 0. Then, I ran the pandas describe function, but I want it to exclude 0 values. How can I do that? Because right now, it shows the 0 values as the minimum of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df["Column_name"] != 0].describe()
```

or

```
data.dropna(inplace = True).describe()
```

Comment: I want pandas to ignore 0 values when calculating describe.

Comment: did you tried data.dropna(inplace = True).describe()

Comment: @AtillaColak Second one doesn't work, it gives an `AttributeError`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most straightforward solution is to hold the `NaN` values and just calling describe. By default the function will ignore the `NaN` values to summarize the data, as stated in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html?highlight=describe#pandas.DataFrame.describe).

Try to save the `data.dropna()` in a new variable or just copy the result without the `inplace` parameter. This is necessary because the return of `data.dropna(inplace = True)` is `None`. You can confirm  this by printing its result:

```
print(data.dropna(inplace = True))  # prints "None"
```

**SOLUTION**

With a new dataframe:

```
new_df = data.dropna(inplace = True)
new_df.describe()
```

Without a new dataframe:

```
data.dropna().copy().describe()
```